# Remix throwing strange errors when used in turborepo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, remix.run, turborepo

I am trying to add remix example for one of my libraries - [react18-themes](https://github.com/mayank1513/react18-themes). I have a working example [here](https://github.com/mayank1513/react18-themes-remix-example). However, when I try to setup the example in the monorepo, it throws strange errors

```bash
TypeError: Unknown file extension ".ts" for ...react18-themes\packages\react18-themes\index.ts
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
remix-example:dev:     at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:79:11)
remix-example:dev:     at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:121:38)
remix-example:dev:     at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:81:20)
remix-example:dev:     at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
remix-example:dev:     at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:605:26)
remix-example:dev:     at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:457:22)
remix-example:dev:     at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:64:26)
remix-example:dev:     at ESMLoader.#createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:480:17)
remix-example:dev:     at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:434:34)
```

It can be reproduced from [this branch](https://github.com/mayank1513/react18-themes/tree/remix). OS - Windows 11.

I am not able to figure out what is going wrong here and why is remix trying to get to the
`packages\react18-themes\index.ts` file, even when I replace `workspace:*` with `^1.0.8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@jrestall](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues/7664#issuecomment-1763401727). I needed to add the following config and also add all the dependencies that were used by the workspace that remix example depended on.

```js
/** @type {import('@remix-run/dev').AppConfig} */
export default {
    ignoredRouteFiles: ["**/.*"],
    watchPaths: ["../../packages/react18-themes", "../../packages/shared-ui"],
    serverDependenciesToBundle: ["react18-themes", "shared-ui"], // <- note this line
};
```

Note this: `serverDependenciesToBundle: ["react18-themes", "shared-ui"]`

Comment: This worked for me using bun workspaces. Thank you!